# How to handle a generic exception generated by a lower method if you can't catch or throw it

Tags: java, spring

I am working in a project which requires that i resolve all pmd errors. Now I have run into the problem that a construct I'm using throws a generic Exception, meaning I can't properly resolve it in my own code, without pmd screeching at me for throwing or catching a generic exception.

Relevant code from org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        if (!this.authenticationManagerInitialized) {
            this.configure(this.localConfigureAuthenticationBldr);
            if (this.disableLocalConfigureAuthenticationBldr) {
                this.authenticationManager = this.authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
            } else {
                this.authenticationManager = (AuthenticationManager)this.localConfigureAuthenticationBldr.build();
            }

            this.authenticationManagerInitialized = true;
        }

        return this.authenticationManager;
    }
```

```
public AuthenticationManager getAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return authenticationManager();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static analysis tools like PMD are useful but imperfect. In general it’s a bad thing to throw Exception because any method calling a method that throws Exception also ends up throwing Exception. Here, however,  the exception is handled by the Spring framework, not in your own code, and propagating the exception is not an issue.

PMD warnings should be carefully checked out, most of them are telling you about things that should be fixed, some of them might not be totally correct but still point to problem code. But some of them are going to be false positives. In this case the boundary between application code and framework code would have to be something PMD was aware of for it to analyze this correctly, but PMD doesn’t know about Spring.

It’s not realistic to expect that all PMD issues should be resolved, PMD doesn’t know about Spring Security and is not telling you anything useful.

Comment: I resolved this with @SupressWarnings then.